# Archer GRC REST API - Outbound?

Tags: rest, api, post, archer

I am looking at integration my platform to an Archer Instance for GRC. I have been reading docs @ RSA so far am left with the impression that my tool can GET/POST to Archer but Archer cannot POST out to my cloud platform.

Anyone have insight if thats incorrect? Any examples or links where Archer POSTS outbound?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, Archer itself can't POST out to your platform.

Here's what I've done in the past:

- Use the Archer API to grab a report (containing the data you want to post to ServiceNow(or other platform))
- Iterate through

  - For each record returned from Archer, format data according to needs
  - POST Data
  - If Success Post, update a field on that archer record (usually a flag or something that made it be on your report to begin with)
  - Log Success or not

The only missing piece of information you need to figure out is "How often do I need this data in my other platform?", but that's the easy part.

Comment: 'Use the Archer API to grab a report' -- How did you do this?  I can't find anything for externally pulling reports via API in the docs.

Comment: When looking to move data from Archer to somewhere else, you can 'pull down'/grab an Archer report using the web service Search class and the method SearchRecordsByReport. That’ll get you your data and it’s up to you to format it in a way that your other system can consume.